# is there an automated way to attach many images each corresponding to one object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, paperclip

i have paperclip and imagemagick and a db of 1000 objects.

is there an automated way to attach 1000 images each corresponding to one object?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own rake task.